# How to sort numbers in TextViews and display them?

Tags: android, sorting, textview

Hi can some one suggest me a sample example of how i can sort the textviews based on the numbers in textviews. I am able to get the text from the TextViews need to sort and place the lowest number first.

Thank you.

```
public void sortNumbers(View v) {

    String[] numbers = new String[7];
    numbers[0] = textView23.getText().toString();
    numbers[1] = textView33.getText().toString();
    numbers[2] = textView43.getText().toString();
    numbers[3] = textView53.getText().toString();
    numbers[4] = textView63.getText().toString();
    numbers[5] = textView73.getText().toString();
    numbers[6] = textView83.getText().toString();

    Integer[] intValues = new Integer[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i].trim());
    }
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(intValues));

    for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; i++) {
        Integer intValue = intValues[i];

        //here I want to assign sorted numberes to the TextViews


    }

}
```

---

So I have followed Jeffrey's advice. Here is the code which still doesn't work properly. What could be wrong?

Created an array of TextViews:

```
TextView[] tvs = new TextView[7];

    tvs[0] = textView23;
    tvs[1] = textView33;
    tvs[2] = textView43;
    tvs[3] = textView53;
    tvs[4] = textView63;
    tvs[5] = textView73;
    tvs[6] = textView83;
```

Sorted the array and assinged new values to the TextViews:

```
    Arrays.sort(tvs, new TVTextComparator());

    textView23.setText(tvs[0].getText().toString());
    textView33.setText(tvs[1].getText().toString());
    textView43.setText(tvs[2].getText().toString());
    textView53.setText(tvs[3].getText().toString());
    textView63.setText(tvs[4].getText().toString());
    textView73.setText(tvs[5].getText().toString());
    textView83.setText(tvs[6].getText().toString());
```

And here is the Comporator class:

```
public class TVTextComparator implements Comparator<TextView> {
    public int compare(TextView lhs, TextView rhs) {

        Integer oneInt = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getText().toString());
        Integer twoInt = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getText().toString());

        return oneInt.compareTo(twoInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: `youtTextView.setText(""+intValue);`

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. do you want the textviews to render on screen in a sorted order?

Comment: The numbers are sorted in ascending order. So the textView23 should display the lowest number and the textView83 should display the highest number. How do I do that?

Comment: Basically all the textviews are in a table's column. And I want to sort that column in ascending order when I click on the column's header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to sort your textViews, first put them in an array,

```
TextView[] tvs = new TextView[7];
tvs[0] = textView23;
tvs[1] = textView33;
// and so on
```

note that if you have handle to the parent container, you could easily build the array by using `ViewGroup.getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`.

now write a comparator for a text view,

```
class TVTextComparator implements Comparator<TextView> {
  @Override
  public int compare(TextView lhs, TextView rhs) {
    return lhs.getText().toString().compareTo(rhs.getText().toString());
    // should check for nulls here, this is NOT a robust impl of compare()
  }
}
```

now use the comparator to sort the array,

```
Arrays.sort(tvs, 0, tvs.length, new TVTextComparator());
```

Comment: I am getting this error message - the method compareTo(CharSequence) is undefined for the type CharSequence. How can I fix it? And another question is can I use ArrayList<TextView> instead of TextView[]?

Comment: public class TVTextComparator implements Comparator<TextView> {
 public int compare(TextView lhs, TextView rhs) {
  Integer oneInt = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getText().toString());
  Integer twoInt = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getText().toString());
  return (oneInt.compareTo(twoInt));
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sortNumbers(View v) {

String[] numbers = new String[7];
numbers[0] = textView23.getText().toString();
numbers[1] = textView33.getText().toString();
numbers[2] = textView43.getText().toString();
numbers[3] = textView53.getText().toString();
numbers[4] = textView63.getText().toString();
numbers[5] = textView73.getText().toString();
numbers[6] = textView83.getText().toString();

Integer[] intValues = new Integer[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i].trim());
}
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(intValues));

  textView23.setText(intValues[0]);
  textView33.setText(intValues[1]);
  textView43.setText(intValues[2]);
  textView53.setText(intValues[3]);
  textView63.setText(intValues[4]);
  textView73.setText(intValues[5]);
  textView83.setText(intValues[6]);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second for loop?